# What would be an Application Architecture Roadmap?

Tags: architecture

I've architect and develop many applications, however this time I'm going to develop a big and different kind of robust application where the below layer will present.

1. Presentation Layer
2. Business Layers
3. Data Access Layer
4. Service Layer

This time I'm more aware of architecting the application.

I'm mainly concern about which Layer should I architect first and which layer is next.

Would you please help me by telling the best order of architecting the layers of the application?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `My focus` is to your answer as: please `re-order the layers first` and `then your suggestions` and `then reference you would like to provide`, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Architect the **user experience** first. The designs of all the layers must satisfy that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: Would you please answer me by reordering the layers and your suggestion and reference you wan to provide, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding You should always develop independent layer first, on which the others will depend. The service layer is the layer which can be deployed separately and can be used by other so 1st develop the service layer then presentation layer because user exp must be taken care then database and then business layer
so go like

1. Service Layer
2. Presentation Layer
3. Database Layer
4. Business Layer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any better suggestion, thanks for your time?

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain, what about this suggestion do you think can be improved? You seem to be looking for something specific so some dialog might help answerers zero in on what you need.

Comment: @Michael, I would be glad to have a bit more detail answer, like the logic why a layer should architect first or next. From my experience an application can be a good one when the users are satisfy and become more popular day by day, so why shouldn't we architect the presentation layer first? These way actually I'm looking for the answer, or if s/he refer any reference where I might see the proper way and logic to architect a layer first or next etc. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should not just think from the user perspective. user just see front end, they never know whats going on in back end.. you should think about oops properties and about N-tier architecture. The component should have low coupling and high flexibility. It should be easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach may be to architect the following way
1) User experience
    You can show the UI to the end client and get a feedback early in your life cycle.
2) Database layer
3) Service Layer

Answer (score 0):

First you should ask yourself if all those layers are really necessary. Usually you would implement one feature after another, where feature crosses layers. Trying to implement one layer, ant then another one only when the first one is finished is too risky for moderately sized application. When implementing a feature, it usually makes sense to start from UI.